# Rails app with test & live data access similar to stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a rails 4 app that exposes API to external users. The users also get access to a web dashboard where they can see & manage data related to API calls, similar to stripe. Stripe dashboard also allows you to switch between live & test data. I am looking to replicate similar behavior. Are there any design recommendations or a Rails way on how to do this? Use separate database (db_live vs db_test) or use separate tables inside db_live, and then use `*_test` table naming convention to access test data inside live database.

Whats the Rails/ActiveRecord way to do this? I am using Postgres as the database.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be to simply add a `live` (or `test`) boolean column to the appropriate database tables and use scopes to apply the desired `where` condition. An index on the column would also help with performance.

The practicality of this solution depends on exactly how test data is generated and how much of it you expect there to be per user/account.

Comment: This is the first solution that came to mind but it'll make the code very open to mistakes and very cumbersome to handle. Or worse yet, the code has to be repeated for live and test environments.

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for the same answer as well. Till now, the best option I can think of is to use a multi-tenant system. You can set a session variable as `test|live` and based on it connect to `different databases` OR in case of `postgres` different `schemas`. This way, all our code will remain DRY and all the switching logic between test and live systems can be moved in a single place.

Here's a basic idea on multi-tenant systems:

http://jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/